# Is there a video on Docker that I could show to business leaders?

Tags: docker

I need to explain the value of Docker to a non technical audience. I have gone to YouTube but the videos are too long and too technical.   Is there anyone who knows of resource to drive a business value based discussion of Docker.  It is a significant technical change that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could also start with some of the keynotes from DockerCon 2014 (just a few are listed here):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DOXBVrlW78
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrxnVKZeqK8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYiXrQWxIVg

I'd also suggest taking a look into the business use cases which can be found here (not videos, but info about how other companies use docker):

- https://docker.com/resources/usecases/

Your question might be framed another way, similar to the stack overflow question here (again, not specifically videos, but consumable information about docker that tries not to dive into the technical detail):

- [Understanding docker from a layman point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916900/understanding-docker-from-a-layman-point-of-view/23917783#23917783)