# Difference between Running and Starting a Docker container

Tags: docker

In practice to **start** a container I do:

```
docker run a8asd8f9asdf0
```

If thats the case, what does:

```
docker start
```

do?

In the manual it says

> Start one or more stopped containers

Comment: run = create + start

Comment: I wish the OP had also included 'execute' as well

Comment: Might be helpful: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/76919

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck There is docker `execute` ?

Comment: You use **start** to a container, if you earlier had **stopped** this container. You use **run** to an image, if you ealier had **removed** a container of this image. This is the basic usage I think.

Answer (score 567, accepted):

This is a very important question and the answer is very simple, but fundamental:

1. Run: create a new container of an image, and execute the container. You can create N clones of the same image. The command is:
   `docker run IMAGE_ID` **and not** `docker run CONTAINER_ID`

[image]

2. Start: Launch a container previously stopped. For example, if you had stopped a database with the command `docker stop CONTAINER_ID`, you can relaunch the same container with the command `docker start CONTAINER_ID`, and the data and settings will be the same.

[image]

Comment: Does a volume need to be created for the stopped container for the data to persist?

Comment: @LoganPhillips Lifecycle difference between files written to container's default _union_ filesystem layer and files written to volumes is: container's union filesystem layer data is always lost when removing the container (`docker rm container_id`). On the other hand, volumes data survive container's removal  unless `-v` option is explicitly supplied on the command line. Volume location on the host system can be directly inspected. [See this article](https://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)

Comment: About process, need `&`  at the end of the `run` command line?  I need it as a countinous (24 hours) service

Comment: So then what is the purpose of "docker create"? How/when would that be used?

Comment: When you do `docker run hello-world` it prints "Hello from Docker!" but when you create a container by doing `docker create hello-world` and then start the container it won't print that output. What's happening there?

Comment: @JosephGagnon: per Fumiski Wells comment above: run = create + start .  Per the doc: "command creates a writeable container layer over the specified image and prepares it for running the specified command.  This is similar to docker run -d except the container is never started." I personnally mostly use docker run from an image, but it's good to have more freedom as this just enable more use cases :).

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara: Create command just prepares the container.  It does not run it.

Answer (score 141):

- `run` runs an *image*
- `start` starts a *container*.

The [`docker run` doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) does mention:

> The `docker run` command first **creates** a writeable container layer over the specified image, and then **starts** it using the specified command.
>
> That is, docker **run** is equivalent to the API `/containers/create` then `/containers/(id)/start`.

You ***do not run an existing container***, you use `docker exec -it` to do it (since docker 1.3), more info at [How do I run a command on an already existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708039/6309). And finally you can restart an exited container, more info at [How to continue a Docker container which has exited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21928864/6309).

Comment: @Tarik don't you have to add `-i` to `docker run` for an interactive process? I mean, docker run needs an image to run a container.

Comment: There seems to be a room to somebody to write a more elaborate response. The answer does not look very explanatory.

Comment: Next question for me was whats-the-difference-between-a-container-and-an-image  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498832/in-docker-whats-the-difference-between-a-container-and-an-image

Comment: and how is `docker exec` different?

Comment: @SohailSi [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) is for running command in a running container.

Comment: Thank you. I keep forgetting that. It is good that it is now mentioned here.

Answer (score 25):

Explanation with an example:

Consider you have a game (iso) image in your computer.

When you `run` (mount your image as a virtual drive), a virtual drive is created with all the game contents in the virtual drive and the game installation file is automatically launched. [Running your docker image - creating a container and then starting it.]

But when you `stop` (similar to docker stop) it, the virtual drive still exists but stopping all the processes. [As the container exists till it is not deleted]

And when you do `start` (similar to docker start), from the virtual drive the games files start its execution. [starting the existing container]

In this example - The game image is your Docker image and virtual drive is your container.

Comment: When you do `docker run hello-world` it prints Hello from Docker! but when you create a container by doing `docker create hello-world` and then start the container by doing `docker start  27c833038489` it won't print that output. What's happening there?

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara:simply, a container always monitors a task, if tasks stops, container stops.  ex: you start a windows server core image, and you run cmd: container will just wait for the process to complete, thus nothing happens until you kill it.  So, in your case, you need to look at what is the task the container you start is doing and there are many ways to do that, and they can supersede each others via command line -it / run ...[COMMAND] --, dockerfile [CMD] or docker-compose.yaml entrypoint:.  It's a bit complicated at first, but this is where it because so powerful and re-usable!

Comment: @ChamithraThenuwara: because `docker run` by default runs in foreground (use `-d` to detach it), whereas `docker start` by default runs in background (use `-a` to run in foreground). So, `docker start -a 27c833038489` WILL print the _Hell from Docker_ message. So much for consistency, eh?

Answer (score 24):

`run` command creates a container from the image and then starts the root process on this container. Running it with `run --rm` flag would save you the trouble of removing the useless dead container afterward and would allow you to ignore the existence of `docker start` and `docker remove` altogether.

[image]

`run` command does a few different things:

```
docker run --name dname image_name bash -c "whoami"
```

1. Creates a Container from the image. At this point container would have an id, might have a name if one is given, will show up in `docker ps`
2. Starts/executes the root process of the container. In the code above that would execute `bash -c "whoami"`. If one runs `docker run --name dname image_name` without a command to execute container would go into stopped state immediately.
3. Once the root process is finished, the container is stopped. At this point, it is pretty much useless. One can not execute anything anymore or resurrect the container. There are basically 2 ways out of stopped state: remove the container or create a checkpoint (i.e. an image) out of stopped container to run something else. One has to run `docker remove` before launching container under the same name.

***How to remove container once it is stopped automatically?*** Add an `--rm` flag to `run` command:

```
docker run --rm --name dname image_name bash -c "whoami"
```

***How to execute multiple commands in a single container?*** By preventing that root process from dying. This can be done by running some useless command at start with `--detached` flag and then using "execute" to run actual commands:

```
docker run --rm -d --name dname image_name tail -f /dev/null
docker exec dname bash -c "whoami"
docker exec dname bash -c "echo 'Nnice'"
```

***Why do we need `docker stop` then?*** To stop this lingering container that we launched in the previous snippet with the endless command `tail -f /dev/null`.

Comment: By far, this is the best answer I've read. Not only answers to OP question, but explain some very useful tipical use cases in a very small space and with examples.
For me, that I'm just starting with this, it did resolve many questions I'd have.
Thanks!

Comment: I agree that this is an excellent answer. However, I am confused by the statement "Once the root process is finished, the container is stopped. At this point, it is pretty much useless. One can not execute anything anymore or resurrect the container. " -- I thought one can `docker start` it again, is that not so?

Answer (score 12):

[daniele3004](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46138763/3363541)'s answer is already pretty good.

Just a **quick and dirty** formula for people like me who mixes up `run` and `start` from time to time:

`docker run [...]` = `docker pull [...]` + `docker start [...]`

Comment: This is not quite true. According to the official doc, `"...docker run is equivalent to the API /containers/create then /containers/(id)/start.` (source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been wiser to name the command "new" instead of "run".

Run creates a container instance of an existing (or downloadable) image and starts it.