# Why docker start is much faster than docker run

Tags: mysql, docker

I use [mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) that start with this command

```
 docker run --name test-mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

when docker run in background, It takes about a minute for another application can connect to port 3306.

After that I stop this container with `docker stop test-mysql` and then start it with `docker start test-mysql`. in the second case, with start command, the application can connect to port 3306, just after 5 seconds.

Now I take a snapshot from stopped container with `docker commit test-mysql mysql2`, and run it with `docker run -d mysql2` but in this case, the application can connect to mysql2 after a minute!

So,

1. What's happen with stopped container, that can be start and responsible just in 5 seconds but mysql image can not do it?
2. Is there any way to take a snapshot after run container, that can be responsible in 10 seconds?

**NOTE:** Mysql image has an entrypoint that it takes above a minute to start.

Answer (score -2):

1. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783353/7719775 for the first Answer.
2. And for the second, you should take a look here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/, but even in this case docker start will be faster than docker run command

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this is not my answer, I asked what is different between container start from stopped container and run from an image. Not definition of that!