# Docker modify iptables of a single running container

Tags: networking, docker, iptables

If this is possible, how can it be done?

I want the changes to modify only rules within a container, not affect any other containers, and not affect the host.

Comment: Do you have IPtables *running* inside the container? In most cases, a container is just a single process, and you should see them as if they're a single binary, so there would be no iptables inside the container, unless you installed it there (and have a process manager, to run multiple processes inside the container). In a default setup, IPtables is running outside the container, and basic rules are managed through docker, i.e. only ports that you "publish" (`-p`) are accessible.

Comment: Don't have iptables, so you're right about that. Guess I was looking for another way to block a published port on an existing running container.

Comment: Mostly you should consider a container "immutable", i.e. opening or closing a port should warrant starting a new container to replace the existing one. With a bit of planning (keeping persistent data outside of the container, and store it in a volume), that should be easy to do, but of course, depends on your situation

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Docker container is a running instance of an image. Any changes in one container do not affect any other container.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498832/in-docker-whats-the-difference-between-a-container-and-an-image%5B1%5D) is one nice answer on dokcer image vs docker container

Comment: I guess you answered the yes/no part of the question, but hoping to get a solution as well.

Comment: Solution for what exactly? I mean, changing IP tables to do what? Block/open port, forward port, allow IP etc...

Comment: see comment above in question